# Как решить проблему с ошибкой IIS HTTP Error 502.5 dotnet 0x80004005:8000808c?

Tags: .net, iis

Всем добрый день! Прошу Вашей помощи! Ошибка распространённая, и имеет массу решений, которые я попробовал и увы без результата.

Я написал API, которое замечательно работало на 2012 iis 8.5, сегодня я немного его доработал(сменил тип полей в модели), в студии всё прекрасно работало, ошибок не было и я опубликовал его на сервере. Ну а дальше, при обращении к api, я получаю `HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure`

В журнале :

`'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/COREAPP' with physical root 'C:\netcore\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\WebApi_Test_01.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 8000808c.`

При запуске из командной строки :

`PS C:\netcore> dotnet c:\netcore\webapi_test_01.dll
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (webapi_test_01.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces', version: '2.8.0'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll'`

Не находит библиотеку. :(

В csproj строки добавил:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework> 

 <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Но ничего не помогает. :(

Посоветуйте, что-нибудь, если Вы сталкивались с такой ситуацией.
Спасибо!

Comment: Данный файл в каталоге есть.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не туда посмотрел. У вас не находит файл `lib/netstandard1.3/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll`

Comment: Геннадий, спасибо Вам! Я нашёл эту библиотеку там, где её не искал... в папке с проектом. `.\WebApi_Test_01\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\PubTmp\Out` и скопировал все библиотеки от туда в каталог с api на IIS. И всё заработало! Спасибо!